# I want to do something after ajaxForm.submit, where to put the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#picture').live('change', function() {
  $("#formupload").ajaxForm({
    target: '#newpic'
  }).submit();
});
```

Basically, when I select a image to upload, it will automatically upload and show the image on `#newpic`. I want to do something after uploading the image, for example, remove the class of `#newpic`, where should I put the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#picture').live('change', function() {
   $("#formupload").ajaxForm({
       target: '#newpic',
       success:    function() { 
            //do stuff here
       } 
   }).submit();
});
```